# Windows Screensaver Installation Location

Tags: windows, installation, screensaver

I have written my own screensaver, which makes use of additional files located at the same directory as the screensaver executable (.scr file).

If I right-click on the screensaver and select '*Test*', all is well, those extra files are found.

But if I right-click and click on '*Install*' to install the screensaver, it seems to not be able to find those files anymore.

Does the installation process make another copy of screensaver, or maybe change the working directory? If so, what directory is it in?

It's a Windows 7 desktop.

So far I have searched in Windows folder, Program Files, Program Files (x86).

**UPDATE:**

So, I added the following bit of code to determine the executable's location.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

It appears that the screensaver is running from the directory where I put it, from the original file. However, after installing it, the only way I can reach files in the same folder from the executable is if I use full paths. If I run it as *Test*, I can simply use filenames only.

This should be a clue as to what is going on, I think. The above function, if I run it as *Test*, returns long file names, but if I run it as *Installed*, it returns short file names. I think that when *Installed*, it runs as some kind of a special process, or maybe a child process, which also interferes with file access.

What is going on?

Comment: The current directory changed.

Comment: Yep, I saw your comment right after I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I added a piece of code to determine the current working directory, and found that when running the screensaver in *Installed* mode, the current working directory becomes **C:\Windows\system32**, which would of course explain how files are referenced.

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```